# In Visual Studio Professional 2017, using 'Generate Method' after 'Show Potential Fixes', how to generate a method stub with NO body

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense, code-snippets, stub

I would like an option in Visual Studio, when selecting `Show Potential Fixes` on a call to a non-existent method, to create a method stud with **no body**.  There is already a code snippet for this,

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodStubNoBody.snippet"

but I can't work out how to get Visual Studio to use that snippet from the 'Show Potential Fixes' option.

The reason the current situation is undesirable, is it adds `using System;` to the file, which then means that all my uses of Random.Range(), are now ambiguous between UnityEngine and System namespaces.

[Visual Studio suggesting to create a method stub WITH a body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akdns.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is unable to generate method without body. I found some other community members already shared this suggestion with the VS product team, please check this: [Generate Method should generate a Block Body, not an Expression Body](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/34635286-generate-method-should-generate-a-block-body-not)

We can vote it and waiting for the response from the VS Product Team.